# Django loggers - Correct output to stdout and stderr

Tags: python, django, logging

Seems that Django loggers default to use stderr for **all** logging levels.

for example when logging setup is:

```
'version': 1,
        'disable_existing_loggers': True,
        'formatters': {
            'default': {
                'format': "%(asctime)s:%(name)s:%(levelname)s:%(message)s"
            },
        },
        'handlers': {
            'console': {
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
                'formatter': 'default',

            }
        },
        'loggers': {
            '': {
                'handlers': ['console'],
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'propagate': True,
            },
            'django': {
                'handlers': ['console'],
                'level': 'WARNING',
                'propagate': False,
            },
            'appname': {
                'handlers': ['console'],
                'level': 'WARNING',
                'propagate': False,
            },
```

When I change handlers to:

```
 'handlers': {
            'console': {
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
                'formatter': 'default',
                'stream': sys.stdout  #Notice the change
            }
        },
```

Then all output is in stdout.

But I need the **correct** behavior: logging info,debug, warning to `stdout` (warning can go either way, don't really care) and exception, error, critical to `stderr`

What am I missing here? (some obvious setting? everybody knows about?) Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try defining 2 handlers, e.g `consoleout` and `consoleerr` each using the correct stream.

Use the correct handler for each entry in the `loggers` section.

Comment: Thanks working! seems I need to add both consoles, and each one would be called according to debug level

Comment: I tried this, but the `consoleout` would print all logs (DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, and CRITICAL), while `consoleerr` only `WAN, ERROR and CRITICAL`. Is there a way to only print DEBUG and INFO on `consoleout`?

Comment: What did you set as `LEVEL`? What's your `LOGGING` config?

Answer (score 0):

We should correct std stream name like in this docs.

```
"stream": "ext://sys.stdout"
```

...

https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#custom-handling-of-levels